# Regex - remove all occurences of a word from the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
nxtisFixed IncomenxtisForexnxtisMoney Marketsnxtis
```

I want to use regex on it so it looks like this:

```
Fixed Income, Forex, Money Markets
```

I've tried this:

```
var withoutnxtis = data.replace(/^nxtis/, "");
withoutnxtis = data.replace(/nxtis$/, "");
```

But it did not work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Remove anchors, use global flag `data.replace(/nxtis/g, "");`

Comment: Trim Split Filter Join. `str.trim().split('nxtis').filter(e => e.trim()).join(', ')`

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var data = "nxtisFixed IncomenxtisForexnxtisMoney Marketsnxtis";
 var withoutnxtis = data.replace(/nxtis/gi, ", ").replace(/^,\s*|,\s*$/g, '');
 console.log(withoutnxtis);
```

Explaination:

> **/nxtis/gi**
>
> **nxtis** matches the characters nxtis literally
>   **(case insensitive) g modifier:** global. All matches (don't return on first match)
>   **i modifier:** insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of
>   [a-zA-Z])
>
> **/^,\s*|,\s*/g**
>
> **1st Alternative: ^,\s***
>        **^** assert position at start of the string
>         **,** matches the character **,** literally
>      **\s*** match any white space character **[\r\n\t\f ]**
>       **Quantifier: *** Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
>
> **2nd Alternative: ,\s***
>   **,** matches the character **,** literally
>   **\s*** match any white space character **[\r\n\t\f ]**
>       **Quantifier: *** Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
>   **g modifier:** global. All matches (don't return on first match)

Comment: Isn't this same as Wiktor's first answer. Except for the `i` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `/^nxtis/` will only match `nxtis` at the start of the string and `/nxtis$/` will match that string at the end. You need to remove that everywhere inside the string.

You can use the following regex based solution:

```js
var re = /nxtis/g;              // A regex to match all occurrences of nxtis
var str = 'nxtisFixed IncomenxtisForexnxtisMoney Marketsnxtis  ';
var result = str.replace(re, ', ').replace(/^,\s*|,\s*$/g, ''); // Replace nxtis with ', ' 
document.body.innerHTML = result; // and remove initial and trailing commas with whitespace
```

An alternative is to remove `nxtis` before the replacement with the comma and space:

```js
var re = /nxtis/g;             
var str = 'nxtisFixed IncomenxtisForexnxtisMoney Marketsnxtis  ';
var result = str.replace(/^\s*nxtis|nxtis\s*$/g, '').replace(re, ', ');
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution. Here's how it should be (*data* is the input string):

```
var re = /((?:nxtis)+)/g;
return data.replace(re, ', ')
           .replace(/^(\s*,\s*)/,'')
           .replace(/(\s*,\s*)$/,'');
```